# Communicating with Microsoft Dynamics GP Database and Project DataBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-gp

I am coding in ASP.NET C#.
I have Microsoft Dynamics GP hosted at a server and my database hosted at another server.
I would like the GP database take value from some table there and synchronise it with my database. Which is the best alternative?
Data transmission Service(DTS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write SQL statements directly or use DTS if what you're doing doesn't require changing any business rules. If you, however, are making changes to the database that need to go through some kind of validation or have some business rules applied, you should use econnect or web services modules.  Hope this helps.